# dotnet-symbol unable to download the symbols for a core dump

Tags: .net, debug-symbols

Running on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/dumps$ dotnet-symbol -d --symbols --server-path http://symbolsrv.xyz.com/symbols/xyz clean_coredump
Downloading from http://symbolsrv.xyz.com/symbols/xyz/
Writing: ./dotnet.dbg
ERROR: Reading PDB records for /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.16/System.IO.FileSystem.dll: Virtual address range is not mapped 00007450DBCF0944 4
ERROR: Virtual address range is not mapped 00007450DBCF0944 4
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/dumps$
```

What is the meaning of this error? How can it be fixed?

I tried to google it but came empty handed.